# Are manual-focus Tamron lenses from 1985-1999 compatible with my Nikon D5100?

Tags: lens, nikon, tamron

Today I met with one of my brothers, and he got some very good lenses made by Tamron: 70-200mm, 18-70mm, 200-650mm.

All of these lenses are from 1985-1999. I know that these lenses are compatible with Nikon. All of them are manual focusing and made for film SLR cameras.

But, are they compatible with my Nikon D5100 DSLR?

I did quick research online, and found that some "Adaptell" can be used to attach the lens to Nikon — but are they available for Nikon D5100?

Please tell me in detail what I need. I extremely need those lenses for
[online photography courses](http://cameranphotography.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The Nikon mount is universal, so if you have an adapter for Nikon, it will mount on the D5100.  It is likely that your camera won't meter with them however.  So not only will you manually focus, but you will probably have to shoot in Manual exposure mode.

If you look about halfway down [this](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm) page you will find what Nikon lens types your D5100 is compatible with.  You may be able to determine what the Adaptall mount is similar to - probably [AI](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/nikortek.htm#ai)